Ubuntu 24.04 in Thinkpad X201i
I want to install ubuntu 24.04 in thinkpad X201i. But, i have problem with my installation. If I run the bootable iso with my fd, my laptop force shut down. I have try to check the checksum is normal. I have change the fd bootable maker with balena, rufus and ventoy, that is similar reaction (off). I have try to change the GPT to MBR or MBR to GPT, nothing change. My BIOS is very old, so there is not button of UEFI or legacy. Any advice?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Does this answer your question? Bootable USB of Ubuntu Minimal CD
